# Как передать значения хэш в метод? Ruby

Tags: ruby

Задание: Напишите код, который адаптирует этот хеш для условий на Луне. Известно, что вес на
луне в 6 раз меньше, чем вес на Земле.
“лунный магазин”. Используя хеш с новым весом из предыдущего задания
напишите программу, которая для каждого типа спрашивает пользователя какое
количество мячей пользователь хотел бы купить в магазине (ввод числа из консоли). В
конце программа выдает общий вес всех товаров в корзине. Для сравнения программа
должна также выдавать общий вес всех товаров, если бы они находились на Земле.

```
hh = {soccet: 410, tennis: 58, golf: 45}
hlun = hh.each { |k, v| hh[k] = v.div(6) } #первую часть задания сделал, посчитан вес на луне
puts hlun
def total_weight(options={})
a = options[:soccer_ball_count] || 0
b = options[:tennis_ball_count] || 0
c = options[:golf_ball_count] || 0
(a * v) + (b * v) + (c * v)

end

print "skolko soccet? "
a = gets.to_i
print "skolko tennis? "
b = gets.to_i
print "skolko golf? "
c = gets.to_i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действия:

- Завел словарь веса на Земле (как константа)
- Добавил функцию, что принимает количество товара и возвращает сумму
- Для получения веса на Луне разделил результат функции на 6

Пример:

```
# Вес на Земле
PRODUCT_BY_WEIGHT = {soccet: 410, tennis: 58, golf: 45}

def get_total_weight(soccet_count, tennis_count, golf_count)
    return soccet_count * PRODUCT_BY_WEIGHT[:soccet] \
        + tennis_count * PRODUCT_BY_WEIGHT[:tennis] \
        + golf_count * PRODUCT_BY_WEIGHT[:golf]
end

total = get_total_weight(10, 5, 10)
puts total / 6;  # Общий вес на Луне
puts total;      # Общий вес на Земле
```

Результат:

```
806
4840
```

---

**UPD.**
Если значения запрашивать из консоли:

```
print "how many soccet_ball?\n"
soccet_count = gets.to_i

print "how many tennis_ball?\n"
tennis_count = gets.to_i

print "how many golf_ball?\n"
golf_count = gets.to_i

total = get_total_weight(soccet_count, tennis_count, golf_count)
puts total / 6;  # Общий вес на Луне
puts total;      # Общий вес на Земле
```

Comment: Спасибо! Функция работает. Там еще по условию  программа должна спрашивать о количестве мячей. пишу: print "how many soccet_ball? "
soccet_count = gets.to_i
print "how many tennis_ball? "
tennis_count = gets.to_i
print "how many golf_ball? "
golf_count = gets.to_i
Не пойму как потом передать эти значения в параметры get_total_weight

Comment: @AlexIlichev, передаете как значения, ведь в этих переменных значения: `total = get_total_weight(soccet_count, tennis_count, golf_count)` ;)

Comment: Почему-то все вычисления завязаны на soccet_count. Если он равен 0, то и total = 0, если soccet_count равен 2, то и total все умножает на 2

Comment: @AlexIlichev, причина была в сложении, учитывалось только первое сложение, т.к. не было экранирования. Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает. Четыре дня не мог решение найти. Не знал про этот слэш \ в методе

Comment: @AlexIlichev, я про него подумал, когда вспомнил про питон (правда, в питоне при такой записи была бы ошибка при отсутствии слеша). Проблем не было бы, если разбили операции или в одну строку записывать или, думаю, обернуть в круглые скобки :)

Comment: @AlexIlichev, проголосуйте и примите, пожалуйста, мой ответ :)